# Make a method that returns csv file in C#

Tags: c#, csv

I've made a method that's doing some csv file creation. For testing purpose I was saving file on file system, but I don't want to do it like this.

This is my code:

```
void ICreateNewCsv.CreateCsvForIndividuals(List<FormattedPerson> formattedPersons)
{
      //var CsvFilePath = "C:\\temp\\individuals.csv";
        var csv = new StringBuilder();
        var toExclude = new HashSet<string>
        {
            "ID",
            "SubSystemID",
            "System",
            "Component"
        };

        var props = typeof (FormattedPerson).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).
                            Where(property => !toExclude.Contains(property.Name));

        var header = string.Join(", ", props.Select(p => p.Name.ToString()).ToArray());
            csv.AppendLine(header);

        for (var i = 0; i < formattedPersons.Count; i++)
        {
             var personTexts = formattedPersons
                 .Select(p => string.Join(",", p.Surname, p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, p.DateOfBirth,
                        p.NationalID, p.Gender, p.Address1, p.Address2, p.Address3,
                        p.City, p.Country, p.PostalCode, p.UniqueID));
             var joined = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, personTexts);

             csv.AppendLine(joined);
         }
         //File.AppendAllText(CsvFilePath, csv.ToString());
}
```

Is there a way to return csv file instead of just having void method?

Comment: replace `void` with `string` and `return csv.ToString();`

Comment: @fubo Will this work? Since I really need to return physically existing csv file when someone invokes this method...

Comment: Well, what do you want to return? The content of the file? A pointer to a file?

Comment: @fubo it will return the pointer to file.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I will have one lets say microservice that will invoke this method and it will be expecting to get real CSV file. So I need to put this content into some .csv file somehow and return that file, not just it's content...

Comment: This looks like fairly poor CSV conversion. What happens when you find your data already has commas in it?

Comment: @spender It will never happened (at least I hope so :P) since data for this file is prepared before and some other method are making sure that it has validate format. So commas will be excluded before this...

Comment: That seems like an unnecessary game of whack-a-mole. Why not use a tested CSV library that handles all the edge-cases such that you can throw any data you want at it?

Comment: @nemo_87: What do you mean with 'returning a file'? Do you want its location (path)? Or its content?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I don't need to save file on my local machine, just need to create it on demand. So somehow I need to find a way to return real lets say test.csv file that has content that I've made in method...

Comment: @spender Can you suggest some tested library, to be honest I've never worked with CSV files before, so I am not that much informed...

Comment: @nemo_87: A file is simply data that's stored in a file-system. The microservice you mentioned either accepts data directly, or wants to read it from a file. In the first case, you can just pass it the data (`return csv.ToString()`) and there's no need to create a file. In the second case, you create a file and pass its location (path or url) to the microservice, which then proceeds to read that file in order to get the data.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to replace `void` with `FileStream`, 
then you will return a *'System.IO.FileStream'* Object that can have the Type of everything (.CSV but also Text or anything else).
Than you would just have to Parse/Use it the way you'd like in the part where you call the Method:

```
FileStream objFile = ICreateNewCsv.CreateCsvForIndividuals(formattedPersons);
```

Comment: `File` is a static class, so you can't instantiate it. You probably meant to use the `FileStream` class. Then again, that's the same as returning the actual csv content, so the file-creating step might just as well be skipped.

Comment: Thus that is the only way, at least I, could think of to return it, except he uses some external libary.

Comment: The thing is that 'returning a file' is an ambiguous phrase in this context, so without clarification it's not clear what the OP really needs.